# R subscript based on a vector

Tags: r, subscript

```
df <- data.frame(name=c('aa', 'bb', 'cc','dd'), 
              code=seq(1:4), value= seq(100, 400, by=100))
df

v <- c(1, 2, 2)
v

A <- df[df$code %in% v,]$value
A

str(A)
```

I tried to obtain the corresponding value based on the code. I was expecting `A` to be of length 3; but it actually returns a vector of 2. What can I do if I want `A` to be a vector of 3, that is `c(100,200,200)`?

Comment: Use `match` instead of `%in%`: `df[match(v, df$code), 'value']`

Comment: don't you just mean `df(v,2)`?

Comment: @PascalvKooten: I imagine not necessarily... if `v` is a vector of codes rather than a vector of indices.

Comment: @jbaums perhaps post your suggestion as an answer, it is most likely the correct one.

Comment: match() works. Thanks everyone. code is not a vector of indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%in%` returns a logical vector, the same length as vector 1, that indicates whether each element of vector 1 occurs in vector 2.

In contrast, the `match` function returns, for each element of vector 1, the position in vector 2 where the element first appears (or `NA` if it doesn't exist in vector 2). Try the following:

```
df[match(v, df$code), 'value']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `v` as an argument if those were the lines whose "value"s you wanted:

```
> df[v,]$value
[1] 100 200 200
```

Comment: Only because in this case `df$code` is the same as the row index.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[v,2] # minimum characters :)
```

Comment: Only because in this case `df$code` is the same as the row index.